# Error with C# mySQL INSERT statement - "You have an error in your SQL syntax"

Tags: c#, mysql, insert, mysql-error-1064

I keep getting the same vague error with this code:

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO database (upc, title, description, quantity) VALUES ('"+ upc.Text +"',"+"'"+titlename+"',"+ "'"+descname+"',"+ "'1'"+"), MyConString";
```

The error is:

> {"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'database (upc, title, description, quantity) VALUES
>   ('016000165779','Betty Crock' at line 1"}

I'm new at C# and trying to build a program that uses UPC codes that get inserted into a mySQL database.

Comment: One of the biggest things that's wrong with it is the [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) hole

Comment: Do any of your variables contain `'`?

Comment: @jadarnel27, agreed! At this point in history there is virtually no reason left to be making queries out of string concatenations. Just learning how to code? Please... don't learn how to code *with SQL injections baked right in!*

Comment: no i don't have the quotes actually being inserted as data. i read examples of the statement and thats how they wrote it

Comment: @DevinPrejean: unfortunately the internet is littered with code samples that wouldn't pass any sort of basic security audit.  Usually written by those that really aren't sure of what they are doing.

Comment: I looked up that SQL injection and that is some serious stuff. However this database and code will be on a local machine in a Windows Form and will not be used by anyone through the network or have outside access

Comment: @DevinPrejean: I hate to beat a bush, but over time we develop coding habits.  In this case you are starting down the path to develop a habit that is an extremely insecure way of doing things.  Sure, it *might* not matter for *this app*; but it will matter someday.  It's much better if you start by doing things correctly; less to retrain on later.  Also, the difference in code between doing it right and doing it wrong is fairly trivial.  So there is really no reason to not parameterize your queries... which is actually the whole problem here.

Comment: @DevinPrejean but still, please don't rehearse wrong practices! It's worthless. Do it right way, although local.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tableName " +
                          "(upc, title, description, quantity) " +
                      "VALUES " +
                          "(@upc, @title, @description, @quantity)";

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@upc", upc.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", titlename);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", descname);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", "1");
```

Notes:

- This fixes your [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) [hole](http://xkcd.com/327/) by using parametrized queries.  Especially where I see `upc.Text`, that makes me think that your concatenating user input into your SQL string (very dangerous).
- I changed the word "database" to "tableName" in your query.  That is where the name of a table goes, not the database name.
- I neatened up your string declaration a little, so that it is easier to read =)

Comment: the name of the table IS database... should i change that to something else i just put a name out there

Comment: @DevinPrejean You definitely want to name the table something more descriptive, like `upcCodes` or `productUPCs`.  Something that describes what is in the table.  As DorSherner mentioned in [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9068030/861565), you can put backticks around the table name if you need it to stay "database".

Comment: oh i changed it and it throws a new error but i think this will be easier. it says the column UPC is out of range. its likely because the number is too big. i set the max to INT(45) on the column but that didn't work.

Comment: @DevinPrejean: the table name should always describe the contents.

Comment: @DevinPrejean: Also don't store UPC codes as numbers... ;) Just use a char() or varchar() field.  You aren't going to be adding them together.  Also, leading zeros can be significant depending on the system.

Comment: Just changed the column to DOUBLE and it worked!! you guys are geniuses! and thanks for patching my security at the same time!

Comment: @Chris is exactly right.  *Definitely* use a text-type field for UPCs.  As you've just experienced, the "numbers" they reprsent will almost always get too large.

Comment: ok i changed it to Varchar(45) and everything works GREAT! thanks again guys.

Answer (score 3):

`database` might be a reserved word. Try escaping it with backticks:

```
INSERT INTO `database` ...
```

I'm also not sure why the `, MyConString` part is inside the query itself, but I'm no C# expert.

Comment: @a1ex07 I get that way too much :(

Comment: well that did change the error finally... but its picking up part of the "description" of the product and throws an error at a certain point. the new error code: {"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's a snap. US inspected and passed by Department of Agriculture.','1'), MyConStri' at line 1"}

Answer (score 3):

Why do you have ", MyConString" at the end of your query?  That seems odd.

Also, `database` is probably not the name of your *table*.

Comment: database is the name of the table, and myconstring is at the end because that identifies the connection. its all in my code i didn't show.

Answer (score 1):

Database is keyword in mysql, try to give descriptive names, so that it will help to understand. and use Parameterized query to avoid sql injections[SqlInjections](http://xkcd.com/327/).

This is the mysql keyword list : [MySql Reserved keywords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html), in future try to avoid using keywords.

```
    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [database] (upc, title, description, quantity) VALUES (@upc,@title ... ) 
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@upc","upcValue");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title","titleValue");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a double quote in the end before the coma:

"+")`"`, MyConString";

Comment: nope. the black is not being picked up. the red colored text is what the program reads